# Tradução de "O(s) motivo(s) de fechamento original(is) não foi(ram) resolvido(s)"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução

Ao clicar para manter uma pergunta fechada, o seguinte diálogo é mostrado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Embora esteja correto no português, a quantidade de parênteses de diferenciação de plural deixa até difícil de ler.

> O(s) motivo(s) de fechamento original(is) não foi(ram) resolvido(s).

Minha sugestão é que deixemos no singular, que semanticamente dá conta do recado. Por exemplo:

> O motivo de fechamento original não foi resolvido.